# What is the Easiest way to extract subset of a 2D matrix in python?

Tags: python-3.x

```
mat = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
         [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
         [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
         [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
         [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
         [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]]
```

Lets say I want to extract upper left 2x2 matrix

```
[[0, 1,],
[6, 7, ]]
```

doing `mat2=mat[:2][:2]` doesnt work.
It extracts the rows correctly but not columns.Seems like I need to loop throughto get the columns.

Additionally I need to do a deepcopy to `mat2` suchthat modifying `mat2` dont change `mat`.

Comment: Does this work for you? `list(x[:2] for x in mat[:2])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `[:2]` returns a `list` containing the first 2 elements of your matrix.

For example :-

```
arr = [[1, 2], [1, 3]]
print(arr[:2]) # will print the first 2 elements of the array, that is [1, 2] and [1, 3], packed into a list. So, Output : [[1, 2], [1, 3]].
```

In the same way,

```
mat = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]]

mat2 = mat[:2] # => [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]]

# Now, if you again try to get the first 2 elements from mat2 you will get the first 2 elements of mat2, not the first 2 elements of the lists inside mat2.
mat3 = mat2[:2] # => [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]]
```

That is where you went wrong, but this concept is quite counter-intuitive, so no worries.

---

So the solution would be to get the first 2 elements from matrix `mat` and then loop over its elements and then get the first 2 elements from them.

Therefore, this should work for you:

```
list(x[:2] for x in mat[:2])
```

Or, as @warped pointed, if you can use numpy, you can do the following:

```
import numpy as np

mat = np.array(mat)
mat[:2, :2]
```